# Open .txt in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, windows, text

[image]Hello I have a dual boot system with Win10 and Ubuntu 20.04 and I want to open Windows notepad files(text document) in Ubuntu so how to open it?

Comment: Did you try to double-click them?

Comment: Yes I tried and it displays that it could not be displayed and their is no other software than symbolic ink to display it and gave me two options to either cancel or to search in software and it does nothing.@Pliot6

Comment: It looks that you are trying to open some symlink, not a file. Right-clicke and open it with gedit.

Comment: I opened it but is showing me just the blank page and the content I have written in it is not displayed@Pilot6

Comment: More details are needed. `txt` files are opened with no problems. It is unclear what exactly you are opening. It seems that it is not really a text file.

Comment: That txt file is written from Windows 10 and access them regularly.In ubuntu I right-clicked them and opened by using text editor and it doesn't worked.@Pilot6

Comment: Can you copy this file to your Ubuntu Home directory and check there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118197/discussion-between-piyush-mhatre-and-pilot6).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured out the problem the text document was in the onedrive folder and was somehow prevented from opening so it was my mistake sorry.Now it can be opened with text editor.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, files ending with `.txt` should automatically be associated with the default text editor (`gedit` for standard Ubuntu).

If that did not happen, try to right-click on the file, select "Open With Other Application", and then choose "Text Editor". In case this option is not shown in the list, try the "View All Applications" submenu.

[image]

Edit: As you have edited the original question - the same works for symbolic links to text files on my system.

Comment: I opened it but is showing me just the blank page and the content I have written in it is not displayed@nspo

Comment: How did you verify that the file actually contains content? It sounds to me like it just might be empty. To be sure, right-click in the folder (not on the file), select "Open in Terminal", and then post the output of `ls -la` and `cat filename.txt` here (of course replace `filename.txt` with the actual name).

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx 2 piyush piyush   25 Jan  2 10:49 'New Text Document.txt' -> 'unsupported reparse point'
@nspo

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ntfs-3g/+bug/1728354 and https://dingyichen.wordpress.com/2019/03/08/fix-ntfs-unsupported-reparse-point/ for some possible background of the problem.